# Android Rxjava2 bindToLifecycle

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

Using Rxjava2 bindToLifeCycle

```
public static <T> LifecycleTransformer<T> bindToLifecycle(ZKBaseView view) {
        if (view instanceof RxAppCompatActivity) {
            return ((RxAppCompatActivity) view).bindToLifecycle();
        } else if (view instanceof RxFragment) {
            return ((RxFragment) view).bindToLifecycle();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("view isn't activity or fragment");
        }
    }
```

当我调动Rxjava进行异步加载的时候，有使用加载框，不过按Home键然后在返回回来，加载框一直存在，不会消失。
我该如何使加载框消失。

edit: google translated text below

When I invoke Rxjava to load asynchronously, there is a load box, but pressing the Home button and then returning back, the loading box is always there and will not disappear. How can I make the loading box disappear?

Comment: Could you write in English please?

Answer (score 0):

将方法换成下面这个就可以了

```
public static <T> LifecycleTransformer<T> bindToLifecycle(ZKBaseView view) {
        if (view instanceof RxAppCompatActivity) {
            //ActivityEvent.DESTROY:在Activity的onDestroy()方法执行后，解除绑定。否则加载框不会消失
            return ((RxAppCompatActivity) view).bindUntilEvent(ActivityEvent.DESTROY) ;
        } else if (view instanceof RxFragment) {
            return ((RxFragment) view).bindUntilEvent(FragmentEvent.DESTROY) ;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("view isn't activity or fragment");
        }
    }
```